# Reverse the layout when using "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding"

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a graph such as

```
NestGraph[# + 1 &, 1, 10, GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> .2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I want to revert the oder like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can we do this in `Mathematica`?

---

**Suggestion:**

In spite of I konw when we do some calculate in a graph,its layout will not impact the result.But I think the layout of a graph is important sometiomes because of human have some demands such as aesthetics,intuition,figuration and so on.Maybe the nouns I use is not very exact,but we very care of its position usually.So I advice the people with permissions of SE establish a tag for this,such as "graph-layout".

Comment: NestGraph[# - 1 &, 11, 10, GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> .2] Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @Prashanth Actually I just simple this quetion.The graph in my case is [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wojpD.png),we cannot by `#-1&` to control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the vertex coordinates from the graph layout with `GraphEmbedding` (thanks to Dr. belisarius for pointing out this simpler alternative to `PropertyValues`):

```
g = PathGraph[Range[1, 11], 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> .2, 
  DirectedEdges -> True]

g = SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> Reverse @ GraphEmbedding[
   g, 
   "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding"
]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For any graph, you can do the following:

```
g = PathGraph[Range[1, 11], GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> .2, 
  DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graph[Reverse /@ EdgeList@g, GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding",
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> .2, 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Just the direction be reverse too.Like the original graph such as 1->2,2->3..We just adjust its layout but direction.

Comment: @yode Sorry, I am not able to understand your English

Comment: I feel so ashamed of it sometimes,but I'm in learning English very hardly recently .  :)

Comment: @yode Don't worry. My English is tarzanic too. Perhaps a native speaker will be able to answer then.

Comment: I feel so lucky to meet you in SE.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I believe what yode is saying is that in the original graph you've got edges `1 -> 2 -> 3` whereas in the new graph you've got `1 <- 2 <- 3`, whereas they *only* want to reverse the layout, not the actual graph itself.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Like this `SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> Reverse@GraphEmbedding[g]]` ??

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Ohhh, `GraphEmbedding`... I just posted an answer doing exactly that, but by retrieving the coordinates manually with `PropertyValue`. Do you mind if I edit that to use `GraphEmbedding`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Not at all. Be my guest

Comment: God,your `SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> Reverse@GraphEmbedding[g]]` is what I want...Beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
NestGraph[# + 1 &, 1, 10,
 GraphLayout -> {"DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", "OptimalOrder" -> False},
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> .2]
```

or

```
PathGraph[Range@11, 
 GraphLayout -> {"DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", "OptimalOrder" -> False}, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", VertexSize -> .2, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As [the documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0cg5b79gi-uvg4ev)."With the setting `"OptimalOrder"->True`, the vertex ordering optimizes the angular resolution and the aspect ratio".The `OptimalOrder` give a perfect solution,but I don't know what did it here.

Comment: Anyway,I have give a upvote.

Comment: I found the `OptimalOrder` don't always reverse the order such as `Graph[Table[i<->i+1,{i,11}],GraphLayout->{ "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding","OptimalOrder"->False},VertexLabels->"Name"]`,The `OptimalOrder->False` is same to `OptimalOrder->True`.