Draw number spirals
I like to draw a spiral of numbers in a grid format (clockwise) of size $n^2$.
So when I pass in $n=2$, it will generate a grid of size $n^2=2^2=4$.

When $n=3$, it will draw a spiral up to 9:

When $n=4$, we have 16:


Clear[g]
g[0] = {};
g[x_] := g[x] = 
  With[{mo = Mod[x, 2] + 1}, {Append, Prepend}[[mo]][
    MapIndexed[{Append, 
         Prepend}[[mo]][#, #2[[1]] + (x - 
          1)^2 + (-2 #2[[1]] + x) (mo - 1)] &, 
     g[x - 1]], ({Reverse, Identity}[[mo]])@
     Range[(x - 1)^2 + x, x^2]]]

Using the above recursive definition:
Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@ g /@ Range[7]



Ulam spiral:
p = 10;
PathGraph[Range[p^2], 
 VertexCoordinates -> (First@Position[Transpose@g[p], #]*{1, -1} & /@ 
    Range[p^2]), VertexLabels -> (x_?PrimeQ) -> x]




Hi @azerbajdzan  as n gets larger, the square won't fit:  Ex:  Grid[#, Frame -> All] & /@ Table[g[n], {n, 800, 800}]   Is there a way just to draw out the last 2 shells only?  Or the outer layer only?

@Steve237 I think 800 is too large to be displayed nicely with full length of all numbers.

Hi @azerbajdzan : I don't want to display it...I want to just list it out as a LIST set {...,...,...,}  the outer layer only.

@Steve237 You can replace inner numbers like so: g[n] /. x_ /; x <= (n - 2)^2 -> Nothing

Clear[n, coords, m];
n = 8;
coords = 
  Threaded@{Ceiling[n/2], Ceiling[n/2]} + 
   FoldList[Plus, {0, 0}, 
    Flatten[Riffle[Table[ConstantArray[(-1)^(k + 1) a, k], {k, 1, n}],
        Table[ConstantArray[(-1)^(k + 1) b, k], {k, 1, 
         n}]]] /. {a -> {0, 1}, b -> {1, 0}}];
m = SparseArray[Thread[coords[[1 ;; n^2]] -> Range[1, n^2]]];
Grid[m, Frame -> All]



We can change {a -> {0, 1}, b -> {1, 0}} to {a -> {1, 0}, b -> {0, 1}} to get counterclockwise.



Another way maybe PathGraph with GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding" and Transpose the matrix.

Clear[n, k, coords, m, g];
n = 8;
k = n^2;
g = PathGraph[Range[k], GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", 
   VertexLabels -> Automatic];
coords = (VertexCoordinates /. 
      AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates]) + 1 // Rationalize;
m = SparseArray[Thread[coords[[1 ;; k]] -> Range[1, k]]];
{g, Grid[Transpose@m, Frame -> All]}



Or NestGraph. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110796/72111

Clear[n, k, coords, m, g];
n = 8;
k = n^2;
g = NestGraph[# + 1 &, 0, k - 1, 
   GraphLayout -> "DiscreteSpiralEmbedding", 
   VertexLabels -> Automatic];
coords = (VertexCoordinates /. 
       AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates]) + 1 // Rationalize // 
   Reverse;
m = SparseArray[Thread[coords[[1 ;; k]] -> Range[1, k]]];
{g, Grid[Transpose@m, Frame -> All]}



A more concise version:
n=5;
pts=ReIm@FoldList[Plus,0,I^-Floor[Sqrt[4Range[n^2-1]-3]-1]];
Graphics[{Line@pts,Point@pts,MapIndexed[Text[Tr@#2,#+{.1,.1}]&,pts]}]


MatrixForm[mat=Partition[Ordering[Cross/@pts],n]]

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 \\
 20 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
 19 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 11 \\
 18 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 12 \\
 17 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

very nice +1 :)

Brilliant, @chyanog   -- concise and short!  Is there a way to display the numbers on the line drawing.

@ubpdqn Thank you.

@Steve237 See my updated answer.

We can define the spiral matrices recursively, by observing when n is odd we add a column to the left of the n-1 matrix, and a row on top, and when n is even we add a column to the right, and a row on the bottom:
sp[2] = {{1, 2}, {4, 3}};

sp[n_] := sp[n] =
  Module[{joinLeftCol, joinRightCol},
   If[OddQ[n],
    joinLeftCol = 
     Join[{Reverse@Range[(n - 1)^2 + 1, (n - 1)^2 + (n - 1)]}, 
       Transpose@sp[n - 1]] // Transpose;
     Join[{Range[ ((n - 1)^2 + n), n^2]}, joinLeftCol]
    ,
    joinRightCol = 
     Join[Transpose@
        sp[n - 1], {Range[(n - 1)^2 + 1, (n - 1)^2 + (n - 1)]}] // 
      Transpose;
    Join[joinRightCol, {Reverse@Range[ ((n - 1)^2 + n), n^2]}]
    ]
   ]

Table[sp[i] // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &, {i, 2, 5}]


I'm guessing there's a much cleaner way to do this however.

Add-on
This is the same thing, but I define the new columns and rows in separate functions to hopefully make it a little easier to stare at. We can also start at sp[0] by defining it to be the empty matrix:
newCol[n_] := 
 Module[{col}, col = Range[(n - 1)^2 + 1, (n - 1)^2 + (n - 1)];
  If[OddQ[n], Reverse@col, col]]

newRow[n_] := Module[{row}, row = Range[((n - 1)^2 + n), n^2];
  If[OddQ[n], row, Reverse@row]]

sp[0] = {{}};

sp[n_] := sp[n] = Module[{joinCol},
   If[OddQ[n],
    joinCol = Transpose@Join[{newCol[n]}, Transpose@sp[n - 1]];
    Join[{newRow[n]}, joinCol]
    ,
    
    joinCol = Transpose@Join[Transpose@sp[n - 1], {newCol[n]}];
    Join[joinCol, {newRow[n]}]
    ]
   ]


Another add-on
I just found @user34757 's answer here regarding Ulam spirals. We can use their ulamSpiral to create our needed spiral by reversing it, and taking the inner rows/columns if n is even:
(*from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96784/72953*)
ulamSpiral[n_] := 
 Permute[Range[n^2], 
   Accumulate@
    Take[Join[{n^2 + 1}/2, 
      Flatten@Table[(-1)^j i, {j, n}, {i, {-1, n}}, {j}]], n^2]]~
  Partition~n

sp[n_] := 
 If[OddQ[n], 
  Reverse@ulamSpiral[n], 
  (Reverse@ulamSpiral[n + 1])[[2 ;; All, 2 ;; All]]
   ]




You can also easily do it using my LatticePointsArrangement function from the Wolfram Function Repository:
pts=ResourceFunction["LatticePointsArrangement"]["CCWSpiralEast",25]
Graphics[{FaceForm[],EdgeForm[Black],MapIndexed[{Rectangle[#1-0.5,#1+0.5],Text[#2[[1]],#1]}&,pts]}]

Giving:

There are 160 different arrangements available in this function.

Interesting function. Aren't the examples in the Details provided twice?

Yeah somehow went awry… will ask them to fix it…

The details section has been fixed.
